# What are the protocols that are used in teamviewer audio chat?

Tags: audio, voip, teamviewer, protocol, audio-conversion

My country is blocking VOIP, so basically I can't make audio or video chats. However when using Teamviewer, it's always possible to make audio and video conferences.

I want to know how is that possible, and what are exactly the VOIP protocols used to allow me chat in audio and video.

Regards.

Comment: TeamViewer is a closed source program which uses its own protocols.

Comment: I need to know why some apps that are generally called (SIP...something) are working very well. Is SIP a protocol of audio conversations?  Can you help me to find what protocols should I use to make an audio chat app that would work despite of the VOIP blocking?

Comment: Can you provide the exact name?

Comment: The app that I used to make audio/video conversations is called Zoiper, it also have a windows version for computer. However the calls quality became so low. But it still work even if the VOIP is banned!